# Add class to only visible divs that are 2nd, 5th, 8th and so on

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class to visible divs only that are 2nd, 5th, 8th, and so on. I found another answer (see below) but it will add a class to every fourth item. I also want to remove that class after they hide. Would it be correct to change "i % 4 == 0" to "i % 3n-1 == 0"?

```
$('#test li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) $(this).addClass('marginLeft');
});
```

Also, would the code below remove that same class if the div is hidden?

```
$('#test li:hidden').removeClass('marginLeft')
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are `li` elements hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm right that you are wanting to add the class to multiples of three less one (2, 5, 8, 11, 14 etc), you could do this:

```
$('#test li:visible').each(function (i) {
    if ((i+1) % 3 == 2) $(this).addClass('marginLeft');
});
```

Because you want one less than multiples of three, this also means 2 more than multiples of 3. So applying the modulus and checking for a remainder of 2 will apply the class correctly.

Note the `i+1`, since the `.each` function index is 0 based, you need to add 1 to get the actual items.

```js
$('#test li').each(function(i) {
  if ((i + 1) % 3 == 2) $(this).addClass('marginLeft');
});
```

```css
.marginLeft {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 0</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The answer to your second question is yes, `:hidden` will select an element that has one of the following true:

> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

See: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: Make sense, Steve! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is `jQuery.fn` plugin to add/remove class using `.each()` and increase start position `+=3`

Use `.addThisClass('marginLeft', true)` to add class.

OR `.addThisClass('marginLeft', false)` to remove class.

```js
jQuery.fn.addThisClass = function(c, b) {
    var a = 1; // start with 2nd index
    var e = $(this);
    e.each(function(i) {
      if (i == a) {
        if (b) $(this).addClass(c);
        else $(this).removeClass(c);
        a += 3; //increase +3
      }
    });
  }
  //to add class
$('#test li:visible').addThisClass('marginLeft', true);

//to remove class
//$('#test li:hidden').addThisClass('marginLeft', false);
```

```css
.marginLeft {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='test'>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: a should be `2`

Comment: @guradio thanks for reply, indexs start with 0,1,2,3,4,5 So 1 === 2nd index please test snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `li:visible:nth-child()` selector with parameter `3n`

```js
$("#test li:visible:nth-child(3n)").addClass("marginLeft")
```

```css
.marginLeft {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="test">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li hidden="hidden">5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
</ul>
```